# How to add SQLiteDataAdapter in UWP C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

What is the Assembly Reference for the **SQLiteDataAdapter** or any other option?

```
public void Load(ItemsControl control, string commandText)
{
    try
    {
        _db.OpenConnection();

        using (SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, _db.Connection))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            control.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    { }
}
```

Comment: See msdn : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/72c4ab3f-e0ef-4a04-9953-1e70d343e771/sqlite-installation-for-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @jdweng WPF and UWP are different things. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

Comment: Why should a reference library change between WPF and UWP?

Comment: I don't think SQLiteDataAdapter is supported, you can use SQLiteDataReader alternatively, don't you want to use EFCore?

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, if you want to use sqlite database, the MS recommends that you use either the [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) or the open-source [SQLite library](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/) built by Microsoft.

I checked the SQLite library, there's no SQLiteDataAdapter class in it.

So, please follow the official document [Use a SQLite database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#choose-an-abstraction-layer) to use sqlite in your UWP app.

Comment: There has got to be a simple conversion for .Net 4.7.2 to .Net 7.  If not, it seems this is regression not progress.  Does anyone have sample code to load a query into a DataTable?